# ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to clean a Pandas DataFrame off its Null values. For this purpose, I want to use `pd.DataFrame().fillna()`, which is apparently a solid soluton for data cleanups.

When running the below code, I am however receiving the following error `ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'`. I tried several options to rewrite the line `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna()`, none of which led to the desired outcome.

Is there any smart tweak to get this running?

```
import string
import json
import pandas as pd

# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("sp500.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame().fillna()
```

Comment: `fillna(0)` replaces `NaN`s with 0. I think you have forgotten to give `fillna` an argument.

Comment: Thanks for this - the approach worked. This is however leading to key errors for any objects I am subsequently calling as part of the DataFrame (e.g. df['date']). Is there any fast tweak for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fillna()` takes parameters to determine how to replace the values, as stated in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

```py
DataFrame.fillna(self, value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None) → Union[ForwardRef(‘DataFrame’), NoneType]
```

The error you get `ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.` tells that you must at least give one of the `value` or `method` parameter. The former being a constant value to set to all null entries, the latter being a method to fill the entries.

For your second remark, your dataframe object will be modified if you set the parameter `inplace=True`, otherwise the method will return a new dataframe object.

Comment: Thanks - the approach worked.  For any objects I am subsequently calling as part of the DataFrame (e.g. df['date']), I am now however receiving key errors. Is there any fast tweak for it? – M. S. just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: I can't tell much without knowing your data structure, but the most likely is that you don't have any `date` column or that your son is not well recognized by the method `pd.json_normalize`. I can only recommend you to check the documentation and compare your json structure with their examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html